# Get function result in another file

Tags: react-native

I have this file `Quiz.js`:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";

export const Quiz = () => {
  let quizes = [];
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("quiz")
    .get()
    .then(result => {
      result.docs.map(doc => quizes.push(doc.data()));
    });
  return quizes;
};
```

Now I am trying to import it in another file:

```
import { Quiz } from "../data/Quiz";
```

When I try to console log the result like `console.log(Quiz)` it returns `[Function Quiz]`.
I am expecting array of objects. What am I doing wrong here ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/30-days-of-react/day-15/).

```js
export const Quiz = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let quizes = [];
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("quiz")
      .get()
      .then(result => {
        result.docs.map(doc => quizes.push(doc.data()));
        resolve(quizes);
      });
  });
};
```

Use it as below

```js
Quiz().then(res => {
  console.log(res);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Still same output.